# maven assembly plugin and spring config xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

The created jar does not find the configuration file

unable to locate spring namespacehandler for xml schema namespace

main

```
  ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
```

pom

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc0Lr.png)

Comment: can you extract jar file and check if resource folder is not included?

Comment: @AmitK resource folder is not included

Comment: thats the reason .. it should be present.

Comment: @AmitK Even if I create this folder and put the configuration there, the error will not go anywhere

Comment: can you upload your code to github , so that i can try it locally ?

Comment: @AmitK https://github.com/MaximCh56/example

Answer (score 0):

```
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```